# Issues Setting Up NLTK within Python Environment

Tags: python, macos, nltk, homebrew

I am new to programming and I am in the process of attempting to download NLTK to work on a chatbot with Python. At the moment, I am running Python 2.7. As per the documentation for the NLTK available, "NLTK requires Python versions 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, or 3.7."

I downloaded Homebrew and ran the commands the documentation suggested, but have gotten error messages.

```
Leonas-MacBook-Air:~ leonaadriennestephanieponce$ sudo pip install -U nltk
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/leonaadriennestephanieponce/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/leonaadriennestephanieponce/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/56/90178929712ce427ebad179f8dc46c8deef4e89d4c853092bee1efd57d05/nltk-3.4.1.zip (3.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.1MB 548kB/s 
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: error in nltk setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-OTcEsN/nltk/
Leonas-MacBook-Air:~ leonaadriennestephanieponce$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 19.1.1
Processing pip-19.1.1-py2.7.egg
pip 19.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.1.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Leonas-MacBook-Air:~ leonaadriennestephanieponce$ sudo pip install -U nltk
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/leonaadriennestephanieponce/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/leonaadriennestephanieponce/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/56/90178929712ce427ebad179f8dc46c8deef4e89d4c853092bee1efd57d05/nltk-3.4.1.zip (3.1MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.1MB 465kB/s 
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: error in nltk setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-vY99RW/nltk/
Leonas-MacBook-Air:~ leonaadriennestephanieponce$
```

Per the documentation available at: https://www.nltk.org/install.html

I attempted the " sudo pip install -U nltk" command, which returned the errors:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: error in nltk setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-OTcEsN/nltk/
```

I also tried the suggestion on the bottom of the documentation page with no luck, specifically "For older versions of Python it might be necessary to install setuptools (see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) and to install pip (sudo easy_install pip)." The following errors resulted:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: error in nltk setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-vY99RW/nltk/
```

Your help is much appreciated! Many thanks from Jupiter, FL, USA!

Answer (score 3):

Try running `sudo -H pip3 install -U nltk`

Comment: I tried  'sudo pip install nltk'  which worked but when I added '-H' flag, it did not work at all. Similarly, I don't know the purpose of '-H' and '-U' though.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by upgrading setuptools:
`pip install setuptools -U --user`

You might not need the `--user`, I needed it because I got a permission error without it.

Comment: I fixed the issue by first installing the setuptools and then tried sudo pip install nltk

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because of lower version of setuptools, you can solve this in three steps.

To check the setuptools version:

```
python -c "import setuptools; print setuptools.__version__"
```

1. Upgrade to latest version of setuptools:

```
 sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

To check the setuptools version:

```
python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__"
```

2. Upgrade or Install nltk latest:

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

3.Check the nltk module:

```
>>> import nltk
```